# If the time is 1:00am Run the function in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Is there a way in C# where if the time in PC or system says 1:00AM the function will run. I know this can be achieved using timer, but how can I do it? The code I am tinkering right now is this:

```
var t = new Timer { Enabled = true, Interval = 1 * 1000 };
        t.Tick += delegate { mem_details(); };
```

But this code runs the function every 1 seconds, Do I need to compute 1:00AM to Seconds so I can do it using this code?

Comment: What is you code going to be doing in the meantime? If the answer is nothing then it's probably better to use the windows task scheduler to re-launch your program at 1:00am (or shortly before) and not be wasting resources.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It will send an xml in a wcf service, so I need the app to run everytime.

Comment: That's not clear.  Damien is asking if your app is doing anything else, or is it just waiting to do this one task every day.

Comment: @J... this thing is just a feature, my app does something aside from it.

Comment: You can run another thread, and it would only do something like `while(true){ if(DateTime.Now.Hours == "1") DoSomething(); }`, but still it would be wiser to use Windows Scheduler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a 1 second timer why not check the time every tick?

EDIT:

Ok I changed my code a bit. It's still a 1 second timer (1000 milliseconds) but now when the timer tick event triggers, it only looks at the current hour and minute. Thus if your program is running a bit slow it will still run your process at 1 AM.

The global variable "lastRunDate" stores the date of when the last process run. This needs to be updated before your process runs just in case your process takes longer than a second to complete.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private String lastRunDate = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lastRunDate != System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            {
                String str = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");

                if (str.Equals("1:00 AM"))
                {
                    lastRunDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    MessageBox.Show(str);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you ask for a 1 second timer, you're not guaranteed to be called exactly once every second. There's a small possibility that you might get the time just at the end of `00:59:59` and the next time your code runs it has just become `01:00:01`

Comment: That's true. Well you can always create a global String variable and set it to the date the operation last ran. In the timer, do a check to see if today's date is not the same as the global variable's date. If not then check the system time just for "h:mm tt".

Comment: @HuH how can I do it??

Comment: I changed my code to include @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggestion. I hope this explains my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look to Quartz scheduler, I suppose it will help
http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Here is an example of how to configure Quartz for different time using cron strings:http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example3.

You can use the online cron generator to select time you need.

Comment: actualy he needs [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) not Quartz. Quartz is for Java

Answer (score 2):

You could always go with Microsoft's Reactive Framework to do this. The schedulers in there are incredibly robust.

You could write this code:

```
var start = DateTimeOffset.Now;
start = start.Date.AddHours(start.Hour == 0 ? 1.0 : 25.0);
/* start is now set for the next 1AM */

/* So schedule it */
Scheduler.Default.Schedule(start, reschedule =>
{
    /* Do you thing as it's now 1AM */

    /* And now reschedule to run tomorrow at 1AM */
    reschedule(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.AddHours(25.0));
});
```

Comment: How can I declare Scheduler? Do I need declare it with 'using'?

Comment: @LucasJuan - You don't need to declare the `Scheduler` as it is a static type. I didn't discuss the return type from the `Schedule` method - it is an `IDisposable` that you can use to cancel the schedule by calling `.Dispose()`. Typically you would keep a reference to the disposable and dispose of it when you exit your form/app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer and check time in it. For example

`var t = new Timer { Enabled = true, Interval = 1 * 1000 };
        t.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) 
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours > 1 && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours < 2)
                {
                    mem_details();
                    (sender as Timer).Enabled=false;
                }
            };`